# Add pseudo-element on Material UI BottomNavigationAction

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, pseudo-element

I've been trying to add a pseudo-element to add an additional UI element to a selected item.
It looks like this (the line that's located above the menu item)

[image]

Here is my code that for some reason not working (the line is not showing)

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
    createStyles({
        root: {
            '& .MuiButtonBase-root.MuiBottomNavigationAction-root.Mui-selected': {
                '&::before': {
                    content: '',
                    display: 'inline-block',
                    width: '32px',
                    height: '3px',
                    position: 'absolute',
                    top: 0,
                    zIndex: 100,
                    background: theme.palette.primary.main,
                },
            },
    })
);
```

```
const TabBar: React.FC<IProps> = ({ value, handlePath }) => {
    const { root } = useStyles();

    return (
        <Container maxWidth="sm" className={root}>
            <BottomNavigation value={value} onChange={handlePath} showLabels>
                <BottomNavigationAction
                    label="Home"
                    value={Routes.HOME}
                    icon={<HomeIcon isActive={Routes.HOME === value} />}
                />
               //others tabs
            </BottomNavigation>
        </Container>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap `content` in single quotation marks.

```
content: '""'
```